# How to create the custom buttons horizontally one below the other in ribbon of Tridion

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

How to place more than one custom buttons horizontally - one below the other in tridion ribbon.

Like we have Check-in, Check-out, Undo Check-out buttons.

I tried in creating more than one custom buttons by placing them in a group, but by default they were getting aligned side-by-side but not one below the other.

Comment: Nice question, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In [one of my articles on Tridion Developer](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/ribbon-item-group) I explained all about how to use the Ribbon Item Group, this fits small buttons under each other, so that you can place 3 buttons in the space of 2 large ones (which are next to each other).

The RibbonItemGroup is not something you can define in the Configuration file of your UI extension, it is a Tridion User Control (.ascx) that you need to specify.

```cs
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ViewItemsGroup.ascx.cs" Inherits="SDL.Examples.UI.Controls.ViewItemsGroup" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Tridion.Web.UI" %>
<c:RibbonItemsGroup runat="server" ID="RibbonItemsGroup">
  <c:RibbonButton runat="server" CommandName="ViewStaging" Title="View in Staging" Label="View In Staging" IsSmallButton="true" ID="ViewStagingBtn" />
  <c:RibbonButton runat="server" CommandName="ViewLive" Title="View in Live" Label="View in Live" IsSmallButton="true" ID="ViewLiveBtn" />
</c:RibbonItemsGroup>
```

The code behind file extends a Tridion.Web.UI.Controls.TridionUserControl and doesn’t need any specific code. To include it in the Ribbon toolbar, you specify the Ribbon Items Group as an extension using the following XML in your Configuration file:

```xml
<ext:extension assignid="ViewItemsGroup" groupid="EditGroup" name="View" pageid="HomePage" insertbefore="PublishGroup">
  <ext:group>~/Controls/ViewItemsGroup.ascx</ext:group>
  <ext:dependencies>
    <cfg:dependency>My.Theme</cfg:dependency>
    <cfg:dependency>My.Commands</cfg:dependency>
  </ext:dependencies>
  <ext:apply>
    <ext:view name="DashboardView">
      <ext:control id="DashboardToolbar" />
    </ext:view>
    <ext:view name="PageView">
      <ext:control id="ItemToolbar" />
    </ext:view>
  </ext:apply>
</ext:extension>
```

Comment: Hi Bart thanks a lot for the info. You mean that we need to create a new  Tridion User Control.ascx exclusively for our button, or we will need to update existing file.

Comment: You indeed need to create your own Tridion User Control in your extension project, you can name it WhatEverYouLike.ascx

Comment: Hi Bart i have created the usercontrol then made the config file. Now i am able to see the labels on the ribbon. But they were in disabled mode always. Please let me know how i can make them enable so that the functionality can be added over them.Please suggest me.

Comment: They are enabled like any other button through the _isAvailable and _isEnabled functions.

Comment: Yes i have isAvailable and isEnabled functions in my js file.

Comment: Should i need to define the visibility of ribboon button while creating the usercontrol? I have even tried to make them enable by adding enable="true" in during button creation tag in usercontrol.  <c:RibbonButton runat="server" CommandName="ViewStaging" Title="View in Staging" Label="View In Staging" IsSmallButton="true" ID="ViewStagingBtn"  enable="true" />. "But it says Tridion Ribbon button doesnt have the public property named enable".

Comment: Hi Bart, I have created the usercontrol and it was appearing on the ribbon but in disabled mode. In the "http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/ribbon-item-group" it was mentioned to include `<ext:issmallbutton>true</ext:issmallbutton>` inside my extension element in the configuration. I have included it in the extension.config file. But i am facing error like "Loading extension failed - has invalid child element 'issmallbutton'. Could you please let me understand where i need to add this.(`<ext:issmallbutton>true</ext:issmallbutton>` ).

Comment: @Pavan, the comments are not supposed to be used for discussions or followup questions, edit and update your initial question so we can provide a better answer or create a new question if its not related anymore

Comment: Useful to know, you may need to change "CodeBehind" to "CodeFile" if you're adding a none compiled source file next to the .ascx file. And the the source needs to include a partial class.