# Javascript on ribbon group

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I managed to get a new ribbon group by following the article mentioned in [How to create the custom buttons horizontally one below the other in ribbon of Tridion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682702/how-to-create-the-custom-buttons-horizontally-one-below-the-other-in-ribbon-of-t)

I'm now trying to get a Javascript running whenever something changes in the Gui (hiding/showing buttons).

I have this in the configuration:

```xml
<!-- In the cfg:groups part -->
<cfg:group name="ClientGuiMods.ContentGroup" description="">
    <cfg:fileset>
        <cfg:file type="script">/Scripts/CreateRibbonGroup.js</cfg:file>
    </cfg:fileset>
    <cfg:dependencies>
        <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME</cfg:dependency>
    </cfg:dependencies>
</cfg:group>

<!-- In the ribbontoolbars add part -->
<ext:extension pageid="HomePage" name="Content" assignid="ContentGroupId">
    <ext:group>~/Scripts/ContentGroup.ascx</ext:group>
    <ext:dependencies>
        <cfg:dependency>ClientGuiMods.ContentGroup</cfg:dependency>
    </ext:dependencies>
    <ext:apply>
        <ext:view name="DashboardView">
            <ext:control id="DashboardToolbar" />
        </ext:view>
    </ext:apply>
</ext:extension>
```

And this in the Javascript:

```js
Type.registerNamespace("ClientGuiMods");

ClientGuiMods.ContentGroup = function ContentGroup(element)
{
    console.log('RibbonGroupCreated');
    Tridion.OO.enableInterface(this, "ClientGuiMods.ContentGroup");
    this.addInterface("Tridion.Controls.RibbonItemsGroup", [element]);
};
```

I've tried different arguments for this.addInterface(), but it never gets called. Is this the correct way? Or is there maybe another way to get a script called on the Home ribbon toolbar?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are trying to do. What do you mean by "I'm now trying to get a Javascript running whenever something changes in the Gui (hiding/showing buttons)."?

Normally you would implement a Command, which you would then hook up to a button. If the command is enabled, the button will be enabled, etc. Then when the button is clicked, the command is executed.

The buttons will regularly be updated automatically, such as when the selection changes in the list.

Comment: @PeterKjaer: I have a ribbon button group, made from an ascx. This part I accomplished by following the article from Bart. I now have a ribbon button group with some button that are also on the home and create ribbons. What I'm trying to accomplish now is to hide the buttons (or commands) that are unavailable, same thing that's happening on the CreateRibbonPage. The difference with the CreateRibbonPage is that I'm doing this all in a ribbon group. I could do this on every button, but then I would probably need to implement each button individually.

Comment: Bottomline is I want to accomplish the same thing I can on a ribbon page, but on just a ribbon group. The solution I provided hooks into the ribbon page where the ribbon group is added (Home in this example) and run the logic here. I'm all open for a better solution.

Comment: From what you just said, I don't see any reason to deviate from the existing Command pattern. If you are looking to avoid code duplication, just make a base class for your various Commands that implements whatever logic you want to use for disabling or hiding the buttons. The point is that your Commands should be independent of where or how the buttons are added.

Comment: @PeterKjaer I understand most of the button logic should be programmed into the command to make it loosely coupled. However in this case the logic of whether it should be visible depends on the ribbon (group) where it's appearing. Most of the code of how to do this was borrowed from the default Create ribbon page where the same stuff is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bart, I tried the solution, but couln't get that to work.

Digging a bit further in the Javascripts in chrome I found there is no hook to fire any extra Javascript as a RibbonGroup (correct me if I'm wrong).

I did however find a way to get to the 'HomePage' RibbonPage and get it to fire events from there.

The extra thing I need is a "c:pagetype='Homepage'" on the RibbonPage named HomePage in the DOM, which isn't there by default. This can be set by including a load event script at the end. 
So now my script looks like this.

```
Type.registerNamespace("ClientGuiMods");

ClientGuiMods.CreateRibbonPage = function CreateRibbonPage(element)
{
    Tridion.OO.enableInterface(this, "ClientGuiMods.CreateRibbonPage");
    this.addInterface("Tridion.Controls.RibbonPage", [element]);
};
ClientGuiMods.CreateRibbonPage.prototype.updateState = function CreateRibbonPage$updateState(stateObject)
{
    //...
    //Ribbonpage logic to update the state of your buttons and groups
};

console.log('Homepage: ' + document.getElementById('HomePage')); //.setAttribute('c:pagetype', 'HomePage');

var ClientScripts = {
    registerHomepage: function() {
        console.log('adding c:pagetype att');

        var homepage = document.getElementById('HomePage');

        if (homepage) {

            homepage.setAttribute('c:pagetype', 'HomePage');


        }
    }
}
if (document.addEventListener && !Tridion.Utils.Dom.isIE)
    $evt.addEventHandler(window, "DOMContentLoaded", ClientScripts.registerHomepage);
else
    $evt.addEventHandler(window, "readystatechange", ClientScripts.registerHomepage);

Tridion.Controls.Deck.registerPageType(ClientGuiMods.CreateRibbonPage, "HomePage");
```

Comment: updated my code example with the missing initialize method, not sure if that makes any difference

Comment: It seems to me that you are moving in the wrong direction here. Could you clarify what you are trying to do (see my comment up top) and perhaps we could find a solution that will fit better with the existing framework...

Answer (score 3):

I never really looked at the group as anything other than a container for commands (read buttons). So the only interface I used is `Tridion.Cme.Command` on the button JavaScript.

But I think what you are looking for is the ControlResource which you can specify in your **ContentGroup.ascx.cs**

```cs
using Tridion.Web.UI.Core;
using Tridion.Web.UI.Controls;
using Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Controls;

namespace ClientGuiMods
{
    [ControlResources("ClientGuiMods.ContentGroup")]
    public class ContentGroup : TridionUserControl
    {
    }
}
```

Now, you can use the `Tridion.ControlBase` interface in your JavaScript.

```js
Type.registerNamespace("ClientGuiMods");

ClientGuiMods.ContentGroup = function ContentGroup(element) {
    console.log('RibbonGroupCreated');
    Tridion.OO.enableInterface(this, "ClientGuiMods.ContentGroup");
    this.addInterface("Tridion.ControlBase", [element]);
};

ClientGuiMods.ContentGroup.prototype.initialize = function ContentGroup$initialize() {
    // the control is initialized here, we can use the following properties now
    var props = this.properties;
    var controls = props.controls;
    var container = this.getElement();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be off mark here, but it sounds like you have a series of buttons under the same group, and you want to have them behave consistently in terms of availability.

I had a similar case where I need to fire the same event on Save, Save & Close and Save & New operations. What I ended up doing was to write the code as a Save command extension (broadly based off Jaime's details [here](http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/2011-sdl-tridion-gui-extensions.html)) and then, from the SaveClose and SaveNew extensions I would call the Save._isEnabled and Save._isAvailable functions to determine whether my commands were available, and the Save._execute whenever the editors clicks on SaveClose & SaveNew.

Not as elegant as Peter's suggestion though, but got the job done.

Comment: Thanks nuno. The requirement by the client is to merge the Home and Create ribbon. Some buttons need to be removed and others shouldn't show up when they're disabled. The buttons don't have extra needs other than their default behaviour. And the tricky part is to get them hidden (like what happens on the Create ribbon e.g. the New Component hides when you're in a structuregroup.) I know it can be done in a command as well, but it seems better to do it the way it's being done on the Create ribbon, where the updateState method of the ribbon takes care of this.

Comment: The Create ribbon just calls the isAvailable method of each Command; the logic for whether or not it's available is wholly encapsulated in the Command itself -- as it should be.